# Como utilizar map en javascript

Tags: javascript, map

Creé una función que toma dos arrays como argumentos y devuelve un array que contenga los elementos comunes entre ambos.

```
function comunes(array1, array2) {
  if(array1.length<array2.length){//Para que siempre el array2 sea el mas largo
    let temp = array1;
    array1 = array2;
    array2 = temp;
  }
  let resultado = [];
  array2.forEach(elemento => {
    if (array1.includes(elemento)) resultado.push(elemento);
  });
  return resultado;
}
```

Pero estoy tratando de volverla mas corta y de no utilizar la variale resultado, por lo tanto mi pregunta es: ***como podría resolver esto utilizando map?*** Lo hice de esta forma y no me ha funcionado

```
function comunes(array1, array2) {
  if(array1.length<array2.length){//Para que siempre el array2 sea el mas largo
    let temp = array1;
    array1 = array2;
    array2 = temp;
  }
  return array2.map(elemento => {
    if(array1.includes(elemento)){
      return elemento;
    }
  });
}
```

El codigo me devuelve esto:
comunes([5,2,6,4],[7,3,5,2]): ,,5,2

Como podría arreglarlo? Desde ya, gracias <3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema es que `map` va a iterar basado en el número de elementos del arreglo, por eso regresa `[ undefined, undefined, 5, 2 ]`, la solución sería agregar un filtro para quitar esos elementos:

`filter(elemento => elemento);`

El cual va a regresar el resultado de elemento si es verdadero (puedes reemplazarlo por `elemento !== undefined` pero esta implícito).

Pero si quieres simplificar más, puedes solamente usar un `filter` sin tener que usar `map` ya que `filter` crea un arreglo nuevo si se cumple la condición, mientras que para cambiar los arreglos puedes usar `[array1, array2] = [array2, array1];` para desestructurar los arreglos en lugar de la variable temporal.

**Edición**

Igual como comenta @MarcePuente, tampoco sería necesario el `if`, porque `filter` se encargaría de crear un nuevo arreglo sin importar el tamaño de los arreglos a comparar (a diferencia de `map`)

```js
function comunes(array1, array2) {
  return array2.filter(elemento => array1.includes(elemento));
}

a = [5, 2, 6, 4];
b = [7, 3, 5, 2];

console.log(comunes(a,b))
```

Referencias:

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[Desestructuración](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: @MarcePuente muchas gracias por la observación, ya edité la respuesta.

Comment: Me gusta anticiparme, ya te di mi voto ;).